# Is there a limit to common boons, and what happens if you reach it?

Tags: hades

In Hades, if you look at the 'normal' boons list, there seems to be 22 slots (4 rows that alternate 5 or 6 slots).

Is that 22 limit a hard limit, and if you reach for your 23rd boon, what happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so lets do some math.

If we believe the wiki: The elysium boss is room #36. So that means there are 36 rooms where you could get something the 6 styx doors.

So we get to 42.

- Bosses and the room before the boss cannot be a boon, (-6, so 36 left).
- The first room of each floor (and the 2 firsts of styx) do not have rewards, ( -5 we get to 31.)
- Out of the 6 doors of styx, there is max 3 boons. (-3, so 28)

So we would only need for the game to give no hammers or boons 6 times out of 28 possibilities (21%) and this can be curved if the player has a heavy boon start.

So knowing all that, I'm gonna go on a guess that the game stops you from getting more than 22 boons.

Answer (score 2):

This may have changed since Fredy31's answer, but as of the current version, it just adds a fifth column of boons once you go over 22.  Presumably, it goes to six columns if you have more than 26, but I can't say I remember seeing it.

I didn't get a screenshot from during my most recent run that went over 22 boons, but here's the after-run record from one where I got up to 27, showing that if there's a cap, it's at least that high.  This screen has room for up to 32 - I don't know what would happen if you managed to get more than that. According to [the wiki](https://hades.fandom.com/wiki/Boons), there is no limit.

[image: 27 boons]